# Installing Homebrew with fish-shell

Tags: homebrew, fish

I recently had a mishap with MySQL and when I uninstalled it from System Preferences it uninstalled Homebrew as well (I checked the erase all files that are related to MySQL, which was probably not the right thing to do).

Anyways, I got everything back to normal but when I try to install Homebrew using the install script on their website:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get this error:

```
fish: $(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(curl)'.
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I tried complying with this error by eliminating the '$' and running:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I then get this error:

```
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/H...
                  ^
-e:1: unknown regexp options - raw
```

This is where I am stuck. I've tried to change my shell but fish is the only one listed in my shell files.

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: MacOS using iterm2 and fish shell

Answer (score 2):

Your second example just begins with `(curl...`. Which doesn't make any sense. Typo? This should work:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e (curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

Also, you could also just run `curl` and save the script to a file (e.g., `homebrew.rb`) then tell ruby to execute that script: `ruby homebrew.rb`.

Comment: Shoot, I'm sorry, that is a typo. I edited the command to the correct one.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part? When I run `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install` I get a bunch of output and can't locate a `homebrew.rb` file.

Comment: @WaterTrash your edit still says `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl...` which is not valid fish syntax. Did you try the command I put in my answer? No quotes. No dollar-sign. As for using curl separate from ruby you need to tell curl to save the output: `curl -o homebrew.rb ...`.

Comment: Yes, I ran your command and there is no output at all. When I add `-o ` I get: `/usr/bin/ruby -e (curl -o -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12427  100 12427    0     0  14788      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14776
/usr/bin/ruby: no code specified for -e (RuntimeError)`

Comment: You can always change to another shell temporarily if you need to just type the shell name i.e. `bash`

Comment: @WaterTrash: You should not be using fish as your interactive shell if you are not prepared to deal with the differences between it and POSIX shells like bash. Hint: execute `echo "(echo yes)"` in fish and `echo "$(echo yes)"` in bash.